# Is a Variable Local or a Global?

Tags: c#, php

Trying to get up to speed on **PHP**.

I'm looking at a basic guestbook form and trying to recreate it with my style.

[image: screenshot0]

The original file has this line:

```
$tmpDir = getenv('TEMP');
```

I know variables in **PHP** do not have to be declared first (irritating, though that may be for me), and with a name like `tmpDir`, it certainly sounds like some local, temporary variable.

So, I'm punching some of the code in using a trial version of [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) because I'm hoping the Auto Complete features of it will help me learn the language a bit faster.

As soon as I get `$t` typed in, Auto Complete shows me what is available.

[image: screenshot1]

So, `$tmpDir` isn't just some local variable to this code?

How would a Dummy like me know this?

[Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) has a **Go To Definition** function, but when I do that in my original example, all it does is highlight the four instances of it in the code.

[image: screenshot2]

So, without having to go out there and memorize every global variable that **PHP** has, is there any way to know what is global and what is not?

I was not able to find `$tmpDir` on [php.net/manual](http://php.net/manual/en/) either.

**UPDATE:**

**superglobal** is the keyword or PHP definition I missed. I was getting my familiar [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c#/info) term **global** confused with PHP's term.

Given that, the answer is:

> If PHP code were to use the superglobal variable `tmpDir`, then the PHP code would have to explicitly call $GLOBALS[tmpDir] to use it.

Thanks go to [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) and [Wayne Whitty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491494/wayne-whitty), though neither of them has put this into an answer. When one of them does, I will mark it.

Comment: It just seems like your IDE is just grabbing every variable definition it sees, regardless of scope.

Comment: Variables in PHP *do* have to be declared if you don't want to trigger errors, there's just no special keyword to do so.

Comment: Are you coming from a strongly typed language by chance? In a dynamically typed language like PHP the type of autocompletion / intellisense you can provide is limited and prone to errors.

Comment: The referenced answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/153923 does not seem to tell me how to look at a variable in code and determine if it is global or local.

Comment: I understand how scope works. What I do not see is how a language noobie is to determine if the variable is local or global, especially since local variables are not required to be declared anywhere.

Comment: @jp2 Is this code in a function and there's no `global` keyword to be found? Then it's local. Otherwise global.

Comment: @jp2 Maybe you could elaborate on what you think "global" means, you may have a misunderstanding there. "Global" is simply the scope for everything not in a function. Don't confuse that with a *superglobal*, which is a variable magically available inside all scopes. You cannot create superglobals in userland code.

Comment: **OH!** So, `$GLOBALS[tmpDir]` would have to be called explicitly to use that global variable? If so, that would be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Quote your array indices, `$GLOBALS['tmpDir']`! `$GLOBALS` is a superglobal array (see above) which holds all variables in the global scope (also see above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$tmpDir = getenv('TEMP');
```

In this case, $tmpDir will always be a local variable unless you specifically set it to be a global variable. However, it might exist in the [global scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Your IDE might not care too much about scope. It could be showing you a list of variable names that you recently typed. Although, in this case, I'd be willing to bet that `$tmpDir` is a local variable that exists in the global scope, which means that it is available for you to use (try printing it out, just to see what happens).

```
<?php
/* global scope */ 
$tmpDir = getenv('TEMP'); 

function test(){ 
    /* reference to local scope variable that doesn't exist */ 
    echo $tmpDir; 
} 

test();
?>
```

If you run the code above, you'll see that it won't work because although `$tmpDir` has been declared in the global scope, it isn't available inside the local scope of the function `test`. This is because `$tmpDir` is not a global variable.

Comment: OK. That's possible. Not only am I new to PHP, but I'm also new to this IDE.

Comment: It's a local variable... unless this whole code is in the global scope...

Comment: How would the whole code be "in the global scope"?

Comment: @jp2code I elaborated a bit more in my answer. Basically, I think you might be confusing global variables and variables that exist in the global scope. In this case, $tmpDir is a local variable that exists in the global scope, which is why your IDE is probably telling you that you can use it.

Comment: @jp2 By not being written or included inside a `function`. Have you really read the linked duplicate? ;-P

Comment: I saw that in the [book I read](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0672329166) and [the reference you gave](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/153923), but I must have misunderstood what they were saying. I understood it to say a global variable in a file or class could not be accessed from within other class functions. God. The PHP way seems so... wrong. I thought that briefly when I read the definitions, but must have twisted it around to fit the logic I saw in my head.

Comment: @jp2code Play around with a few scope examples and you'll quickly catch onto it.